# Is there any compiler available for HAL/S?

Tags: space-shuttle, software

The [HAL/S programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL/S) is used in the general purpose computers in the space shuttle. I have written a simple HAL/S program of my own. Is there any compiler available to turn it into executable form?

Comment: What platform do you want the compiler to run on? What platform do you want the resulting binary to run on? Would you be willing to settle for an interpreter, or do you need a compiler?

Comment: For whatever it might be worth, [the HAL/S specification is available online by way of the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20090226213557/http://klabs.org/richcontent/software_content/hal_s/hal-s_language_specification.pdf). At a grand total of 237 pages including empty pages, preambles, indexes and other supplementary material, it shouldn't be that hard for someone who wants to implement an interpreter to do so, at least as long as you don't require the language's real-time guarantees.

Comment: I just need a compiler. I have found some references for writting a simple hal/s program using arithmetic functions. 
But how can I execute that for an output ?

Comment: It is not meaningful to ask for a compiler without specifying what you want the compilation target to be. I presume that you aren't looking to run your program on an AP-101.

Comment: Yes.  I don't need to develop a program for AP-101 or anything else. I just need a compiler which can execute my simple functional program,  if it is available.  How can i check whether it is have some error or not?

Comment: You are missing the point of what I'm asking. A *compiler* is a program that takes an input in some form, and generates an output in some other form; in common usage, a compiler takes a human-readable source code input and emits a computer-executable binary. That output binary will be generated for whatever output architecture the compiler is targetting. (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) The answer to "does there exist a compiler that accepts HAL/S source code?" is binary: either such a compiler exists ("yes") or it does not ("no"). The question you want to ask is most likely "please name a compiler that accepts HAL/S source code and emits an IA-32 Win32 PE executable" or "please name a compiler that accepts HAL/S source code and emits an x86-64 Linux ELF executable" or something else along those lines (but we can't know which!). You also don't need a *compiler* to execute your program, or check it for errors; for that, an interpreter would be sufficient.

Comment: I need a compiler that accepts hal/s source code to generate the output.

Comment: @Aldo_Joseph can you say why an interpreter is not good enough? I think it may be.  Also, what machines do you have available to run it on?

Comment: i just have a notebook computer

Comment: For a notebook or similar, it looks difficult. Apparently HAL/S is poorly connected with PL/I, and a very basic PL/I extension for gcc (Linux) was done once but might not be maintained.  It sounds like a fairly expert project to get something working to the full specification.

Comment: @Aldo_Joseph I'm curious why you want to learn HAL/S. Is it just for the novelty? You do realize that the Shuttle program was discontinued, right?

Comment: yeah..its ok .i just try to know about that

Comment: "I just need a compiler which can execute my simple functional program, if it is available." – A compiler cannot execute programs. A compiler is a program which translates a program from one language to another language. "How can i check whether it is have some error or not?" – You could check it by hand, by comparing it to the specification. Essentially, "interpret" it by hand / in your head / with pen and paper. You could also prove it correct with respect to the specification.

Comment: "I need a compiler that accepts hal/s source code to generate the output." – *Which* output? A compiler translates from some language *to* some language. So far, you have only stated what language you want to translate *from*. You also need to state what language you want to translate *to*. (It would also be helpful to know what language the compiler should be *in* so that you can run it.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48613/discussion-on-question-by-aldo-joseph-is-there-any-compiler-available-for-hal-s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general: if there are any compilers still extant for HAL/S, then they are under the care and responsibility of the United Space Alliance, which has published [a specification](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_intermetrimspecification_5514399). There are no HAL/S available as e.g. open source.

More specifically: the question can not completely be answered, as the request for a compiler always includes a target architecture, e.g. "Linux x64".

Comment: May be my words were wrong in the question.. But my expected answer is the same...Thanks for the answer

Comment: United Space Alliance is defunct - it went completely out if business. It has no facilities or personnel any more, and it had no successor - its only business was operating the shuttle program. I worked there.

Comment: Actually HAL/S is similar to Fortran and we can compile it in windows.

Comment: @OrganicMarble From what I can tell, United Space Alliance still legally exists – http://www.unitedspacealliance.com/ claims it is dissolved but Delaware corporate records say otherwise (and surely it must exist to own that website). It no longer performs any active business, but still has some residual functions related to maintaining the employment records of former employees and pension administration. I don't know what happened to USA's corporate archives–did they go to Boeing/LockheedMartin, NASA, or maybe they are still in USA's possession?

Comment: @SimonKissane No idea about the archives. NASA and contractors are horrible at retaining historical material, USA is probably a drawer in somebody's desk at Boeing and an email address forwarded to somebody at LM. It's gone. All the pension stuff is done by a life insurance company. USA was kind of a shell company anyway - a joint entity of Boeing and LM, dreamed up to avoid a contract competition.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the source code to the original HAL/S-FC compiler: [PASS.REL32V0](https://github.com/virtualagc/virtualagc/tree/master/yaShuttle/Source%20Code/PASS.REL32V0)

Ron Burkey at the Virtual AGC project got that code, apparently from the private collection of one of the former HAL/S developers. (At the time I originally wrote this answer, he did not have all the source code to the compiler, but since then he has managed to acquire the complete source code.)

It is written to run on IBM mainframes under MVS, and is written in a PL/I dialect, XPL (and also some IBM mainframe assembly language). XPL survives (see [here](https://www.jaymoseley.com/hercules/compilers/XPL.htm), [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/XPL/), and [here](https://github.com/virtualagc/virtualagc/tree/master/yaShuttle/Source%20Code/XPL-TWS-1969-03)), although possibly not the exact version which the HAL/S compiler was written in. It is not going to run on your PC, unless you are running MVS (or z/OS) under an emulator such as Hercules or IBM zPDT. You would need a high degree of competence with IBM mainframe technologies (or be willing to spend the time learning them) to get anywhere with it.

Apparently only two compilers ever existed (although the first was really a family of closely related compilers rather than a single one):

- this compiler, the original one, written to run on IBM mainframes. From there it was ported to also run on Modcomp minicomputers, and Data General Eclipse minicomputers. Those minicomputer platforms are (nowadays) even more obscure than IBM mainframes, and the use of them was discontinued much earlier, so the odds that those ports will turn up is not promising.
- NASA Langley Research Center wrote a HAL/S compiler in Pascal to run on CDC Cyber mainframes. ([source](https://hopl.info/showlanguage.prx?exp=583)). Not publicly available, *maybe* survives in some private collection or NASA archive, but again the odds are not promising.

Actually this original compiler existed in two main versions–one which generated code to run on the Space Shuttle itself (and simulators which contained real AP-101S flight computers interfacing with simulated hardware), the HAL/S-FC compiler; and one which generated code to run on IBM mainframes, the HAL/S-360 compiler. The HAL/S-360 compiler was used to write utilities and applications to help manage the software development process. This code is from the HAL/S-FC compiler. I assume the HAL/S-360 compiler would have been mostly the same code just with a somewhat different backend, but I don't fully understand the differences between them. The IBM  System/4 Pi architecture of the Space Shuttle's AP-101 CPUs is a derivative of the IBM System/360 mainframe architecture, removing instructions/features which weren't relevant to realtime aerospace applications, and adding some which were useful for them – so I expect the two backends are likely relatively similar code. There were also a bunch more versions of the IBM mainframe HAL/S compiler to produce code for other target platforms, including RCA 1802, Modcomp and ITEK ATAC-16M – this was part of a largely unsuccessful push to get NASA to standardise on HAL/S as a language, by making it available on other platforms popular for NASA projects; but the only major NASA project which actually ended up adopting it (other than the Shuttle) was (one component of) JPL's Galileo probe to Jupiter, which used the ATAC-16M backend.

Comment: "one which generated code to run on the Space Shuttle itself" And the simulators! We had real AP101s in the Shuttle Mission Simulator. Great answer!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for the feedback, I edited my answer to mention HAL/S-FC compiler targeted the simulators as well as the actual Shuttles

Comment: The 5 AP-101s in their rack for the simulator (the Simulator Interface Device) https://i.imgur.com/bieFh7v.png and a close up of a data plate https://i.imgur.com/xKttJbp.jpg